# How to sort array of objects from derived template class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, templates

Here I have array of objects from the class `ColVol`, which defines three - dimensional point with `int` - type color and volume(`int` too). The task is to sort the array by volume if the color is between [1,10]. The error is that `the expression must be modifiable lvalue`?Here are only the declarations of the functions. I don't know what type of sorting will be best here and why gives me that error whentempvariable is  `int, object.get_method() (`in this case the array is`f[] and f[i].get_volume()`isint`)? They are the same type.

```
template<class T> class Point3 {
    T x, y, z;
public:
    Point3();
    void print() const;    
}; 
template<class T, class U> class ColPoint3 :public Point3<T> {
    U color;
public:
    ColPoint3();
    void print() const;
};
template<class T, class U, class V> class ColVol :public ColPoint3<T, U> {
    V volume;
public:
    ColVol();
    void print() const;
    V get_volume() {
        return volume;
    }
};    
int main() {
    const int n = 2;
     ColVol<double, int, int>  *f;
    f = new ColVol<double, int, int>[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f[i];
    }
            int temp;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (f[k].get_color() >= 1 || f[k].get_color() <= 10) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
                for (int j = 0; j < n - i + 1; j++) 
                    if (f[j].get_volume() > f[j + 1].get_volume()) {
                        temp = f[j].get_volume();
                        f[j].get_volume() = f[j+1].get_volume();
                        f[j + 1].get_volume() = temp;   

                    }
                 }
            }
}
```

Comment: what does "volume" mean for a 3D point with color?

Answer (score 1):

You need following fixes (at least to make this compile):

add method get_color to ColPoint3:

```
U get_color(){
    return color;
}
```

change signature of get_volume:

```
V& get_volume() {
 ^~~~!
    return volume;
}
```

and finally define your constructors

[edit]

as for sorting, why not std::sort ?

```
std::sort(f, f + n, [](auto &lop, auto  &rop){
    return lop.get_volume() < rop.get_volume();
    });
```